# Is it possible to consistently refer to forward-declared and non-forward-declared structs in C?

Tags: c, struct, typedef, forward-declaration, function-prototypes

This doesn't work for `foo`

```
struct Foo;

typedef struct
{
    int x;
}
Bar;

void foo (Foo *); // unknown type name ‘Foo’

void bar (Bar *);

typedef struct
{
    int y;
}
Foo;
```

This doesn't work for `bar`

```
struct Foo;

typedef struct
{
    int x;
}
Bar;

void foo (struct Foo *);

void bar (struct Bar *); ‘struct Bar’ declared inside parameter list

typedef struct
{
    int y;
}
Foo;
```

Some of my structs have to be forward-declared, because they are passed as pointers, and some of them have to be not forward-declared, because they are passes as values.

Is there a way to declare types in C such that all function prototypes can consistently always refer to custom types in the same way, regardless of whether they are forward-declared or not?

Comment: In you examples there is no `struct Foo`. There is struct without a tag that you typedef as `Foo`.

Comment: C isn't C++....

Comment: To reduce noise, and with this reduce confusion, just drop all those `typedef`s. `typedef`s are *not* needed at all to get things going.

Comment: A type definition is not the definition of a forward declared structure. It is a completely different thing.

Comment: Using `struct Foo` and `struct Bar` everywhere, as in `void bar (struct Bar *)`, eliminates this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not forward-declared vs. non-forward-declared, it's `struct X` vs. `typedef struct { ... } X`.

You can solve this by using `struct X` only:

```
struct Foo;

struct Bar
{
    int x;
};

void foo (struct Foo *);
void bar (struct Bar *);

struct Foo
{
    int y;
};
```

Once you have that, you can introduce `typedef` names:

```
typedef struct Foo Foo;

typedef struct
{
    int x;
}
Bar;

void foo (Foo *);
void bar (Bar *);

struct Foo
{
    int y;
};
```

You can't pre-declare `typedef`s, so we still need a real `struct` type we can forward to. There's a small inconsistency here: `Foo` is the same as `struct Foo`, but there is no `struct Bar`, only `Bar`. You can fix that by switching to

```
typedef struct Bar
{
    int x;
}
Bar;
```

This defines `struct Bar` and `Bar` simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct Foo;
```

Declare a structure named `Foo`. But, you must declare a typedef `Foo` of structure named `Foo`.

```
#include  <stdio.h>

typedef struct Foo Foo;

typedef struct {
    int x;
} Bar;

void foo(Foo *);

void bar(Bar *);

struct Foo {
    int y;
};

int main(void) {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first order of business is to point out that in your examples there is no `struct Foo`. There is only a struct without a tag that you `typedef` as `Foo`.<sup>1</sup>

> Is there a way to declare types in C such that all function prototypes can consistently always refer to custom types in the same way, regardless of whether they are forward-declared or not?

The definition or declaration of the `struct` should appear before the struct is used in a function parameter list. Otherwise the declarations scope is only the function prototype, which is almost certainly not what you want.

The way to achieve what you want is only through disciplined coding.

A forward declaration is all you ever really need for a function prototype. You don't need the full struct definition until the function itself is defined or called.

```
struct Foo;
void foo (struct Foo); // Okay, only at the call site or definition site
                       // do we need the full struct definition.
```

A short [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/938a036f63dcd189) to demonstrate

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Foo;
void foo (struct Foo);

struct Foo
{
    int y;
};

int main(void) {

    struct Foo f = { .y = 1 };
    foo(f);

    return 0;
}

void foo (struct Foo f)
{
    printf("%d", f.y);
}
```

It's much clearer that it's okay when the definitions and declarations are spread out among different translation units, but the above will have to do.

So what I suggest to you, is that you always forward declare your structs on a separate line, before they are to be used in function prototypes (by pointer or by value). And refrain from introducing the full definition until it's really needed.

---

<sup>1</sup> A lovely correspondence on [fa.linux.kernel](http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/typedefs.html) where Linus Torvalds articulates far better than me why you should prefer to use the full struct tag.

Comment: Very nice discussion about using `typedef`s at the [link](http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/typedefs.html) that you provided. Thanks for this.

Answer (score -1):

The only "forward declaration" and reference supported by C is the pointer, e.g.:

```
void myFunc (struct XYZ *p);
```

This tells the compiler you are referring to a type `struct XYZ`, possibly not yet declared, of which you are passing a pointer. This allows the compiler to perform type checking without knowing what this structure actually consists of.

Note that pointers are all the same size, so there is no check on the pointer itself, just on the thing it is pointing to.

See also other solutions that explain using `typedef`.

Comment: "*The only "forward declaration" and reference supported by C is the pointer*" not entirly true, as you *could* as well ("foward") declare `struct XYZ;`;

Answer (score -2):

You mix up forward declaration and type definitions. Both are different things. If you want to have the same kind of usage of forward declared structs do it:

```
struct Foo;             // forward declaration
struct Bar { int x; };  // definition

void foo(struct Foo);   // works for a prototype
void bar(struct Bar);   // works for a prototype
```

You cannot forward *declare* type *definitions*. Maybe this is the reason for the name *definition*. However, you can type define a forward declaration:

```
struct Foo;                // forward declaration
typedef struct Foo Foo_t;  // type definition of a forward declaration
struct Bar { int x; };     // definition
typedef struct Bar Bar_t;  // type definition of a definition

void foo(Foo_t);           // works
void bar(Bar_t);           // works
```

If you have a function *definition* the type has to be completed. This means that you have already defined the forward declared type at this location or that you have to use pointers. Again: It does not matter, whether you use structures or type definitions.

BTW: As you can see in my examples, it is an urban legend that incomplete structure types has to be passed "by reference". You can use the incomplete type in the function declaration (prototype). However, when you *define* the function, the type has to be completed. This is no deal in most cases.

Comment: [You should refrain from naming your types with a `_t` suffix](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Reserved-Names.html).

Comment: I know that, but this is an example and for teaching purpose it is better to have a strong connection between the identifier of the struct and the type definition on it. As you can see in the Q, I splitted that only for the purpose of demonstrating that struct declarations/definitions are different from type definitions.

Comment: Than a simple `_s` suffix would have worked, without teaching a bad practice. Great for you that you know, don't trip others with poor examples.

Comment: I do not know, what sypedef is. BTW: Using `Foo` and `Bar` as identifiers is poor, too.

Comment: `_s` is for `struct`. `Foo` and `Bar` are illustrative, `_t` is not. If you want to insist on keeping your example poor, that's your problem.

Comment: Great. Then it is my problem.